# Integrate LinkedIn login using JS API

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api, login-script

I am trying to integrate Login In Using LinkedIn. I am use LinkedIn's Javascript API. I have generated an application and API key. Then I have successfully imported their framework as mentioned in their example. I am not getting the login button it shows some error

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: my_api_key
  authorize: true
</script>

<body>
 <script type="in/Login">Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.</script>
</body>
```

When I specify the script in body, the tutorial says a LinkedIn sign in button appears,
but for me an error prompts

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/casarevi/public_html/lsign.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 2):

While the RIGHT thing to do here would be to turn off short_tags (as Adam has suggested), an easy workaround here is to change the code to read:

```
<script type="in/Login">
Hello, <?php echo '<';?>?js= firstName ?> <?php echo '<';?>?js=lastName ?>.
</script>
```

LinkedIn's Javascript API will treat this as the same.  Works like a charm without having to change your .ini settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PHP short_tags enabled?

Comment: That's your problem. Try disabling them.